# Lowest common ancestor for multiple vertices in networkx

Tags: python, networkx, lowest-common-ancestor

How can I compute the lowest common ancestor (LCA) for a directed graph in `networkx` for a subset of vertices?

For example, for the graph

```
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from([(1, 2), (1, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5)])
```

vertex `3` is the LCA for the vertex `{4, 5}` and vertex `1` for the the nodes `{3, 4, 5}`. In case it matters: All vertices are leaves.

[`nx.lowest_common_ancestor()`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.lowest_common_ancestors.lowest_common_ancestor.html#networkx.algorithms.lowest_common_ancestors.lowest_common_ancestor) is not suitable since it requires a pair of vertices, but does not allow a set of vertices.

Thanks!

Comment: what is the expected output for pair `{3, 5}`?  `nx.lowest_common_ancestor()` will give `3`. But I think you expect `1` as result.

Answer (score 1):

After checking the [source code](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/_modules/networkx/algorithms/lowest_common_ancestors.html#generate_lca_from_pairs) of the [nx.lowest_common_ancestor](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.lowest_common_ancestors.lowest_common_ancestor.html#networkx.algorithms.lowest_common_ancestors.lowest_common_ancestor), I found the function for calculating the LCA with a pair of  **2** nodes.

So I did some modifications for this code can work for multiple nodes and return to node `1` not node `3` when the input nodes are `{3, 4, 5}`.

```
import networkx as nx
from functools import reduce

def update_ancestor_cache(node, ancestor_cache, G):
    if node not in ancestor_cache:
        ancestor_cache[node] = nx.ancestors(G, node)
        ancestor_cache[node].add(node)
    return ancestor_cache

def generate_lca_from_pairs(G, pairs):
    ancestor_cache = {}
    if isinstance(pairs[0], int):
        raise nx.NetworkXError("LCA needs at least two nodes") 
    for i in range(len(pairs[0])):
        node = pairs[0][i]
        ancestor_cache = update_ancestor_cache(node, ancestor_cache, G)

    common_ancestors = reduce(set.intersection, (set(val) for val in ancestor_cache.values()))

    if common_ancestors:
        common_ancestor = next(iter(common_ancestors))
        while True:
            successor = None
            for lower_ancestor in G.successors(common_ancestor):
                if lower_ancestor in common_ancestors and lower_ancestor not in pairs[0]:
                    successor = lower_ancestor
                    break
            if successor is None:
                break
            common_ancestor = successor
        yield (pairs[0], common_ancestor)

    return generate_lca_from_pairs(G, pairs)
```

Here shows the result of the codes :

```
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from([(1, 2), (1, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5)])

pairs = [(4, 5)]
dict(generate_lca_from_pairs(G, pairs)) #{(4, 5): 3}

pairs = [(3, 4, 5)]
dict(generate_lca_from_pairs(G, pairs)) # {(3, 4, 5): 1}

pairs = [(1, 2)]
dict(generate_lca_from_pairs(G, pairs)) # {(1, 2): 1}
```